# Can't seem to reset $scope variable in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, timeout, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to reset a $scope variable in my controller when a url parameter changes, but I'm having some trouble with it holding on to old values.

I have a site I'm building for a law firm and if I click to one of the attorney's bios from any page except the bio page itself, it works fine. But, if I try to click to a new attorney's bio page when I'm already on the bio page, it doesn't seem to reset my $scope.thisAttorney variable but rather creates a second instance of it.

The problem with this is that I have a box with rotating quotes about the current attorney that's set up with a timeout function. So, when this problem hits, it has two sets of quotes rotating in that box. I need it to forget about the first attorney when I click on the second attorney's bio.

Here are what I think are relevant files. Please just ask if you need to see something else.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("LKSU", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) { 
$routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'content.php',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })

    .when('/bios/:user_id?', {   
        controller: 'AttorneyController', 
        templateUrl: 'bio.php'
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
```

AttorneyController.js

```
app.controller('AttorneyController', ['$scope', '$location', 'attorneys', '$sce', '$routeParams', function($scope, $location, attorneys, $sce, $routeParams) {

$scope.myFunctions = {};

var practiceareas = {
    altdispute: "Alternative Dispute Resolution",
    businesscorp: "Businesses & Corporations",
    estateplanning: "Estate Planning",
    futures: "Futures & Derivatives",
    litigation: "Litigation",
    productliability: "Product Liability",
    realestate: "Real Estate",
    securities: "Securities"
};

function quoteflip(quotelist, id, total){
    clearTimeout(timeoutQuotes);    

alert($scope.thisAttorney.name + " 1");  // This is how I know it's holding onto the first attorney in $scope.thisAttorney

    var idno = (id + 1) % total;
    $("#bio_quotes").html(quotelist[id]);
    var src1 = quotelist[idno];

    $("#bio_quotes").fadeOut(500, function(){
        $("#bio_quotes").html(src1).fadeIn(500);
    });

    timeoutQuotes =  window.setTimeout(function(){quoteflip(quotelist, idno, quotelist.length);}, 5000);
    }

var timeoutQuotes = "";

attorneys.success(function(data){
    if($routeParams.user_id > 0){
        var matches = $.grep(data.attorneys, function(obj) { return obj.id == $routeParams.user_id; });

        if (matches.length === 1) {
            $scope.thisAttorney = "";
            $scope.thisAttorney = matches[0];
            $scope.$apply();
            var src = $scope.thisAttorney.quotes[0];
            $("#bio_quotes").html(src).fadeIn(500);

            clearTimeout(timeoutQuotes);

            $scope.attorneys = data.attorneys;
            $scope.practiceareas = practiceareas;
            timeoutQuotes =  window.setTimeout(function(){quoteflip($scope.thisAttorney.quotes, 0, $scope.thisAttorney.quotes.length);}, 5000);
    }

    }else{
        $scope.myFunctions.bio_id = 0;
    };


});


}]);
```

Thoughts?

For the record, I tried to put quoteflip in the main script.js but timeout call couldn't find it so I had to bring it back into the Controller. If anyone has a fix for that, i.e.: sees my problem, please feel free to comment on that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Angular's $timeout service documentation can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

You just need to pass this in as an additional controller dependency:

```
app.controller('AttorneyController', ['$scope', '$location', 'attorneys', '$sce', '$routeParams', function($scope, $timeout, $location, attorneys, $sce, $routeParams) { .... }
```

So

```
window.setTimeout(function(){quoteflip(quotelist, idno, quotelist.length);}, 5000);
```

Becomes

```
$timeout(function(){quoteflip(quotelist, idno, quotelist.length);}, 5000)
```

If you could provide a plunk with the relevant code this would be helpful also.

Comment: Using $timeout didn't change anything, nor did changing my apply line to $scope.$apply("thisAttorney");  I'd do a Plunk, but those always get messed up every time I try. Apparently, I'm not too good at them. Sorry. :(

Comment: Could you try setting the $scope.thisAttorney property when you "click on the second attorney's bio" using ng-click maybe. Can you use Chrome developer tools to debug the javascript? If not you could add another alert inside the bit of the code where $scope.thisAttorney gets set to see if this code is getting run.

Comment: I'll try the click thing and see if that works. I know it's getting in there via alerts, like you suggested. The problem is, in the quoteflip function, when I alert it, it shows one name, then also alerts the other name. It's like I have two timeouts going, with different quotes and a different $scope.thisAttorney. I've tried to cancel the timeout, as you can see, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I went to try it and realized I'm not sure how to do that since $scope.thisAttorney is actually an object from within the larger object of all attorneys brought in from a JSON file. Setting it is a few step process. :(

Comment: Ah okay. I would try the "sources" tab in Chrome developer tools and debug through the controller and the code that creates the $scope.this Attorney JavaScript object. Just make sure that everything is firing as and when you expect it to. You may need to re-structure the methods so that they all fire once in the order you wish.

Comment: @ReverendDovie here is a good doc on debugging JavaScript in Chrome's dev tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging . You want to find the controller file and the file which creates the JavaScript object in the sources tab's file view. You should then add a breakpoint to the main methods to try and get a clearer picture of where each function is being triggered. I hope this helps you out and I am not just telling you what you already know?

Comment: I will try that and see. But, again, the new information is there. It's the fact that the old information is stuck as far as JS is concerned. Things like `{{thisAttorney.name}}` on the page are updating correctly, so `$scope.thisAttorney`is updating.  But there seems to be almost a "ghost" version behind the scenes in a timeout that won't die.

Comment: According to developer tools, it's changing back and forth, but I can't figure out where?

Comment: You could try temporarily commenting some of the calls and then re-adding them back in to narrow your search. Just as a way of trying to find out what is causing the value to get set back to the old object. It sounds like you are making progress in finding out what is going wrong though :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `$timeout` rather than `window.setTimeout`? You probably need it because your `$scope` isn't being applied-on this non-angular async service.

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout. That has an automatic $apply build in so your values will be digested and updated on screen.

Comment: The onscreen values updated. The problem is that, somehow, the old one is still lurking, along with its recursive timeout call, in the background,wreaking havoc.